# LD: Different ways to use ALIGN()

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, memory-alignment

What is the difference between these?

```
mysection ALIGN(4): {...}
```

and

```
mysection: {. = ALIGN(4); ...}
```

and

```
. = ALIGN(4); 
mysection: {...}
```

Are the results the same?

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
$ cat foo.c
int mysym __attribute__((section(".mysection"))) = 42;

$ gcc -c foo.c
```

**Case 1**

```
$ cat foo_1.lds
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    .mysection ALIGN(8): {
        *(.mysection)
    }
}

$ ld -T foo_1.lds foo.o -o foo1.out
$ readelf -s foo1.out

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
     4: 0000000000010008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 mysym

$ readelf -t foo1.out | grep -A3 '.mysection'
  [ 1] .mysection
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010008  0000000000010008  0
       0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

**Case 2**

```
$ cat foo_2.lds
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .mysection : {
        *(.mysection)
    }
}

$ ld -T foo_2.lds foo.o -o foo2.out
$ readelf -s foo2.out 

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
     4: 0000000000010008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 mysym

$ readelf -t foo2.out | grep -A3 '.mysection'
  [ 1] .mysection
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010008  0000000000010008  0
       0000000000000004 0000000000000000  0                 4
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

**Case 3**

```
$ cat foo_3.lds
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    .mysection : {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        *(.mysection)
    }
}

$ ld -T foo_3.lds foo.o -o foo3.out
$ readelf -s foo3.out 

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010004     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS foo.c
     4: 0000000000010008     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 mysym

$ readelf -t foo3.out | grep -A3 '.mysection'
  [ 1] .mysection
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010004  0000000000010004  0
       0000000000000008 0000000000000000  0                 4
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

So, **Case 1** is equivalent to **Case 2** . Both of them align `.mysection` to
the next 8-byte boundary, 0x10008, after 0x10004, and `mysym` is at the same address.

But **Case 3** does *not* align `.mysection` to 0x10008. It remains at `0x10004`.
Then the location counter is aligned to 0x10008 after the start of `.mysection`,
and `mysym` is at that address.

In all cases the address of the first symbol in `.mysection` is 0x10008, but
only in **Case 1** and **Case 2** is that the address of `.mysection`

**Later**

> How is case 2 affected if I have multiple sections placed into different memory regions?

Whenever the script invokes:

```
. = ALIGN(N);
```

it simply sets the location counter to the next `N`-byte aligned boundary after
its current position. That is all. So:

**Case 4**

```
$ cat bar.c
char aa __attribute__((section(".section_a"))) = 0;
char bb __attribute__((section(".section_b"))) = 0;

$ cat bar.lds 
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    }
    . = 0x20004;
    .section_b : {
        *(.section_b)
    }
}

$ gcc -c bar.c
$ ld -T bar.lds bar.o -o bar.out

$ readelf -s bar.out

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000010008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000020004     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bar.c
     5: 0000000000020004     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 bb
     6: 0000000000010008     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 aa

$ readelf -t bar.out | egrep -A3 '(section_a|section_b)'
  [ 1] .section_a
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000010008  0000000000010008  0
       0000000000000001 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
  [ 2] .section_b
       PROGBITS               PROGBITS         0000000000020004  0000000000020004  0
       0000000000000001 0000000000000000  0                 1
       [0000000000000003]: WRITE, ALLOC
```

Here, `. = ALIGN(8);` has the effect that `.section_a`, and the first object within it,
`aa`, are aligned to the first 8-byte boundary, 0x10008, after 0x10004. But `. = 0x20004;`
moves the location counter to an address that happens not to be 8-byte aligned, so `.section_b`
and its first object `bb` are not 8-byte aligned. Indeed, if we deleted `. = 0x20004;` then
`.section_b` and the object `bb` would be placed right after `aa`, at `0x10009`.

Comment: How is case 2 affected if I have multiple sections placed into different memory regions?

Comment: @oyvind Hi. Extended answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I was inspired to try a few more things. I put it in an answer because of length.

Comment: You're free to incorporate it into your answer so we have all info in one place.

Comment: Np, it will do for me. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I did my own experiment based on @Mike Kinghan's cases. The numbers don't quite line up with his cases, but test the same techniques, but using multiple memory regions.

Observations:

1. Mike's case 1 (my case 2 and 3) fails to link at all.
2. Mike's case 2 (my case 1) fails to align the variable `bb` in the expected way.
3. Mike's case 3 (my case 5) successfully aligns the variable `bb`
4. Using `SUBALIGN` (my case 4) correctly aligns the variable `bb`, but would also align every input section in that output section.

#### Case 1

```
$ cat bar.c
char aa __attribute__((section(".section_a"))) = 0;
char bb __attribute__((section(".section_b"))) = 0;

$ gcc -c bar.c

$ cat bar1.lds
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000001, LENGTH = 0x100000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    } > RAM
    _myvar = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_b : {
        *(.section_b)
    } > FLASH
}

$ ld -T bar1.lds bar.o -o bar.out

$ readelf -s bar.out
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000020000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000001     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bar.c
     5: 0000000000000001     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 bb
     6: 0000000020000000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 aa
     7: 0000000020000001     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _myvar
```

#### Case 2

```
$ cat bar2.lds
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000001, LENGTH = 0x100000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    } > RAM
    _myvar = .;
    .section_b ALIGN(8) : {
        *(.section_b)
    } > FLASH
}

$ ld -T bar2.lds bar.o -o bar.out
ld: address 0x20000009 of bar.out section `.section_b' is not within region `FLASH'
ld: address 0x20000009 of bar.out section `.section_b' is not within region `FLASH'
```

#### Case 3

```
$ cat bar3.lds
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000001, LENGTH = 0x100000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    } > FLASH
    _myvar = .;
    .section_b ALIGN(8) : {
        *(.section_b)
    } > RAM
}

$ ld -T bar3.lds bar.o -o bar.out
ld: address 0x9 of bar.out section `.section_b' is not within region `RAM'
ld: address 0x9 of bar.out section `.section_b' is not within region `RAM'
```

#### Case 4

```
$ cat bar4.lds
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000001, LENGTH = 0x100000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    } > RAM
    _myvar = .;
    .section_b : SUBALIGN(8){
        *(.section_b)
    } > FLASH
}

$ ld -T bar4.lds bar.o -o bar.out

$ readelf -s bar.out
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000020000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000008     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bar.c
     5: 0000000000000008     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 bb
     6: 0000000020000000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 aa
     7: 0000000020000001     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _myvar
```

#### Case 5

```
$ cat bar5.lds
MEMORY {
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000001, LENGTH = 0x100000
    RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x10004;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    .section_a : {
        *(.section_a)
    } > RAM
    _myvar = .;
    .section_b : {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        *(.section_b)
    } > FLASH
}

$ ld -T bar5.lds bar.o -o bar.out

$ readelf -s bar.out
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000020000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000001     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS bar.c
     5: 0000000000000008     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 bb
     6: 0000000020000000     1 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 aa
     7: 0000000020000001     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _myvar
```